# Memcached correct configuration in local.xml

Tags: cache, server, memcached

I have strange issue with memcached configuration with my Magento setup

here is my `local.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
    <cache>
        <!-- <backend>apc</backend> -->
        <backend>memcached</backend>
            <prefix>MYTAG_</prefix>
            <memcached>
                <servers>
                    <server>
                        <host><![CDATA[127.0.0.1]]></host>
                        <port><![CDATA[11211]]></port>
                        <persistent><![CDATA[1]]></persistent>
                    </server>
                </servers>
                <compression><![CDATA[0]]></compression>
                <cache_dir><![CDATA[]]></cache_dir>
                <hashed_directory_level><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_level>
                <hashed_directory_umask><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_umask>
                <file_name_prefix><![CDATA[]]></file_name_prefix>
            </memcached>
        </cache>
        <install>
            <date><![CDATA[Fri, 01 Feb 2013 06:28:50 +0000]]></date>
        </install> 
        <crypt>
            <key><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]]></key>
        </crypt>
        <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
        <resources>
            <db>
                <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                <connection> 
                    <host><![CDATA[xxxxxxx]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[xxxxxxxx]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[xxxxxxx]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[xxxxxxxx]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
        </resources>
        <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>

<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers><log><type>enabled</type></log></observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
        <controller_action_postdispatch>
            <observers><log><type>enabled</type></log></observers>
        </controller_action_postdispatch>
        <customer_login>
            <observers><log><type>disabled</type></log></observers>
        </customer_login>
        <customer_logout>
            <observers><log><type>disabled</type></log></observers>
        </customer_logout>
        <sales_quote_save_after>
            <observers><log><type>disabled</type></log></observers>
        </sales_quote_save_after>
        <checkout_quote_destroy>
            <observers><log><type>disabled</type></log></observers>
        </checkout_quote_destroy>
    </events>
  </frontend> 
</config>
```

All the caching files are generated in Magento's setup `var/cache` its not directly using memcached directory and every time it is getting full.

In correct manner `var/cache` should always remain empty.

Will you please help me to set correct way of memcached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example of Memecached: It looks like yours is a little different. Have you confirmed that memcache is working? btw: REDIS is a much faster option.

```
<cache>
    <backend>memcached</backend>
    <slow_backend>database</slow_backend>
        <memcached>
        <servers>
            <server>
            <host><![CDATA[127.0.0.1]]></host>
            <port><![CDATA[11211]]></port>
            <persistent><![CDATA[0]]></persistent>
            <weight><![CDATA[2]]></weight>
            <timeout><![CDATA[10]]></timeout>
            <retry_interval><![CDATA[10]]></retry_interval>
            <status><![CDATA[]]></status>
            </server>
        </servers>
        <compression><![CDATA[0]]></compression>
        <cache_dir><![CDATA[]]></cache_dir>
        <hashed_directory_level><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_level>
        <hashed_directory_umask><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_umask>
        <file_name_prefix><![CDATA[]]></file_name_prefix>
    </memcached>
</cache>
```

Comment: brentwpeterson, thanks for your valuable reply.Is in your configuration `var/cache` empty every time?

Comment: The cache directory is created but it is empty.